# How to use curl post method while the login info is required?

Tags: shell, post, curl

For example, if I wanna issue a post request to the server. But the website requires the username and password to login first. How should I do these two operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's requires some programmatic username and password built into the web page, you'd need to submit what it expects for a user logging in, then capture the cookies you get, and then send those cookies back with your post. This can get involved if the login process involves multiple pages which are redirected to. curl can do this, but be prepared to spend some time on it.

To get the cookie being returned by the server, use `curl -i` to include headers. You can also add `-L` to automatically follow redirects (which you otherwise would have to do manually by retrieving the URI in the `Location:` field of an HTTP 301 or 302 response). Example:

```
curl -i -L stackoverflow.com > /tmp/so.html
grep -i 'Set-Cookie:' /tmp/so.html
```

Yields:

```
Set-Cookie: prov=31c24327-c0bf-474d-b504-fc97dc69ab61; domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
```

(Until you get the predictable logic right and how you need to submit the requests, you'll need to inspect the rest of the headers to be able to accomodate redirects, see if there are multple cookies, etc.)

To submit a cookie, use `curl -b`:

```
curl -b "prov=31c24327-c0bf-474d-b504-fc97dc69ab61" [rest of curl command]
```

Be patient and good luck, and be sure to check the `curl` man page.

Comment: How to save the data into the cookie using curl? And how to send back the cookie to the server?

Comment: Updated answer to provide general guidance on that.

Comment: I used mac and safari. When the website is stackoverflow.com, I got the same result. But when I use the other website, below is the cookie file I got:
HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
Date: Mon, 16 Jun 2014 04:56:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/18.0
Vary: Cookie
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Location: example.com
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000

There's no line includes 'Set-Cookie'.

Comment: An HTTP 302 code is a redirect. You can either add `-L` to your `curl` line to follow redirects, or manually look at the `Location:` field and then have `curl` retrieve whatever URL is there. Until you get an HTTP 200, you haven't actually loaded the web page that will have the cookies.

Comment: @IvanX ... Does this cookie ("prov=31c24327-c0bf-474d-b504-fc97dc69ab61") has some lifetime or i can use the same (which i get using curl -i command) cookie for ever ?

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -u username:password -X POST --data "name1=value1&name2=value2" http://yourwebpage.com/
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The login page is different from the the page I am sending my data to.